# Navigating to another page in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Seems trivial enough, but I'm trying to navigate my app inside Cordova's `onDeviceReady()` event handler (on an Android device emulator).

The following code line doesn't handle the string as a pathname, but rather as the full URL - and I'm getting the error below:

```
window.location = '/admin/items?dateRange=week';
// I've also tried `window.location.href` without success
```

[image: The error I'm getting on the Android emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after opening my mind to non-StackOverflow results, I figured the issue was with `cordova-plugin-whitelist`, which allows navigation in Cordova apps.

Apparently the default navigation is indeed to `file://`, as explained [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#navigation-whitelist).

In order to solve this I had to add the following line to config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.mydomain.io/*" />
```